# Android ClassNotFoundException after adding a class to the project

Tags: android

So I had my project working. I am sending objects through a socket connection so I had to add a class to my client side (android project). Now I get this exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [LDB.LuceneSearchEngine$LuceneSearchResults;
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2258)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1418)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:759)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.Client.run(Client.java:82)
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "DB.LuceneSearchEngine$LuceneSearchResults" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2258) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1418) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:759) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983) 
                                                                    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940) 
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.Client.run(Client.java:82) 
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77) 
                                                                    at com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61) 
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DB.LuceneSearchEngine$LuceneSearchResults
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 19 more
                                                                 Caused by: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: Class is not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

`LuceneSearchEngine.java` is the class I just added. There is another class declared inside `LuceneSearchEngine` which is `LuceneSearchResults`.

I tried to delete this classes and create them again with a slightly different name. When I run I get that exception even if I remove that class from the project.

The strange thing is that I created a new project and pasted old classes. Then I added `LuceneSearchEngine` and `LuceneSearchEngineResults` but named them differently. I got exactly the same exception even though those classes were never added to the new project.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding but it doesn't work.

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
package com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness;

import java.io.File;

// TODO: create final strings for hardcodede stuff...

public class LuceneSearchEngine {


    public static class LuceneSearchResults
{
    private static String userSearch = "";

    public String getUserSearch() {
        return userSearch;
    }


    public static void setUserSearch(String userSearch1) {
        userSearch = userSearch1;
    }



    private String product_code;
    private String adv_name;
    private String category;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String gift_included;
    private String product_name;
    private String product_desc;
    private String product_aff_link;
    private String product_pic;
    private String price_no_vat;
    private String price_vat;
    private String free_shipping;


    public LuceneSearchResults()
    {
        product_code = null;
        adv_name = "";
        category = null;

    }


    private static int productScore(LuceneSearchResults result)
    {
        int score = 0;

        if(LuceneSearchResults.userSearch.contains(result.product_code))
            return 666;
        else
        {
            if(LuceneSearchResults.userSearch.contains(result.adv_name))
                score+=4;

            if(LuceneSearchResults.userSearch.contains(result.manufacturer))
                score+=3;

            if(LuceneSearchResults.userSearch.contains(result.category))
                score+=2;

            if(LuceneSearchResults.userSearch.contains(result.product_name))
                score++;

            return score;
        }
    }

    // quicksort

    private static int partition(LuceneSearchResults results[], int left, int right)
    {
        int i = left, j = right;
        LuceneSearchResults tmp;
        int pivot = productScore(results[(left + right) / 2]);

        while (i <= j) {
            while (productScore(results[i]) < pivot)
                i++;
            while (productScore(results[j]) > pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = results[i];
                results[i] = results[j];
                results[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        };

        return i;
    }

    public static void quickSort(LuceneSearchResults results[], int left, int right) {
        int index = partition(results, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(results, left, index - 1);
        if (index < right)
            quickSort(results, index, right);
    }

    //

    // getters and setters

    public String getProduct_code() {
        return product_code;
    }



    public void setProduct_code(String product_code) {
        this.product_code = product_code;
    }



    public String getAdv_name() {
        return adv_name;
    }



    public void setAdv_name(String adv_name) {
        this.adv_name = adv_name;
    }



    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }



    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }



    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }



    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }



    public String getGift_included() {
        return gift_included;
    }



    public void setGift_included(String string) {
        this.gift_included = string;
    }



    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }



    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }



    public String getProduct_desc() {
        return product_desc;
    }



    public void setProduct_desc(String product_desc) {
        this.product_desc = product_desc;
    }



    public String getProduct_aff_link() {
        return product_aff_link;
    }



    public void setProduct_aff_link(String product_aff_link) {
        this.product_aff_link = product_aff_link;
    }



    public String getProduct_pic() {
        return product_pic;
    }



    public void setProduct_pic(String product_pic) {
        this.product_pic = product_pic;
    }



    public String getPrice_no_vat() {
        return price_no_vat;
    }



    public void setPrice_no_vat(String string) {
        this.price_no_vat = string;
    }



    public String getPrice_vat() {
        return price_vat;
    }



    public void setPrice_vat(String string) {
        this.price_vat = string;
    }



    public String getFree_shipping() {
        return free_shipping;
    }



    public void setFree_shipping(String string) {
        this.free_shipping = string;
    }





}



public static final File INDEX_DIRECTORY = new File("IndexDirectory");



public int getHitsCount()
{
    return -1;
}

public void createIndex() {

}

public LuceneSearchResults[] search() {
    return null;
}


public static void main(String[] args)  {

}
}
```

Client.java // here

```
package com.shoppiness.radu.shoppiness;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Client {

private LuceneEngine.LuceneSearchResults[] serverMessage;
public static  String SERVERIP = "5.15.110.111" ; // your computer IP
// address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 3316;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;

PrintWriter out;
ObjectInputStream in;

/**
 * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages
 * received from server
 */
public Client(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;

}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 *
 * @param message
 *            text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient() {
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {

        // here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Log.e("serverAddr", serverAddr.toString());
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        // create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        Log.e("TCP Server IP", SERVERIP);
        try {

            // send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            // receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the
            // server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = new LuceneEngine.LuceneSearchResults[1000];
                serverMessage = (LuceneEngine.LuceneSearchResults[]) in.readObject();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    // call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    Log.d("Radu:", "Object recieved!");
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage[0].getAdv_name());
                    Log.d("WIN::", serverMessage[0].getAdv_name());
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '"
                    + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            // the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to
            // this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to
            // be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

// Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will
// must be implemented in the MyActivity
// class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(Object message);
}
}
```

connectTask.java

```
 public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Client> {

    @Override
    protected Client doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a Client object and
        Log.d("Radu:", "new client");
        mClient = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(Object message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                Log.d("Radu:", "publishProgress...");
                publishProgress(message.toString());
            }
        });
        mClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        Log.e("OBJECT_RECIEVED:", values[0].toString());
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list

    }
}
```

Comment: show me your LuceneSearchEngine.java and manifest file

Comment: @PCGALIANDROID I edited the question and added those things.

Comment: at where are you using show me that activity

Comment: It is used in that while(mRun)

Comment: change LuceneEngine.LuceneSearchResults[] To LuceneSearchEngine.LuceneSearchResults[]

Comment: I did. Nothing changed. Firstly it was like this then i just pasted code from LuceneSearchEngine to a new class called LuceneEngine and tried like that... but it's all the same.

Comment: First declare object of LuceneSearchEngine and then declare array,

Comment: Also you need to set the value first and then after you can use that class

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I'm declaring: private LuceneSearchEngine.LuceneSearchResults[] serverMessage;

Comment: Oh. I see you mean initalizing objects of array. for(int i = 0; i<serverMessage.length; i++)
                        serverMessage[i] = new LuceneSearchEngine.LuceneSearchResults();

Comment: also add value in that

Answer (score 1):

The log is very clear about it:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DB.LuceneSearchEngine$LuceneSearchResults
```

You are trying to load the class `LuceneSearchEngine$LuceneSearchResults` from package `DB`.

In the code posted the package for that class is `com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness`.

Also from the log the error start at `com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness.MainActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)` so it's better to look there for the error.

**Update**

You send the "wrong" object and when you read it in the following line you get the class cast exception:
`serverMessage = (LuceneEngine.LuceneSearchResults[]) in.readObject();`

The problem is the package of the class.

Comment: I copied this class from a eclipse project. There I have a package called DB(database).

Comment: And some where in your code you reference at that class using the `DB` package and not`com.shoppiness.radu.jshoppiness` .

Comment: I edited my question and added the code you are reffering to.

Comment: That was the first thing I thought about. So I decided to create a fresh project. I just pasted my classes in the new project, added string values and included internet permission. I cant tell where I am reffering to that package.